# How to create a button dynamically in android without extending Activity

Tags: android, button, dynamic, android-activity, dynamically-generated

I have a class in android that extends Fragment. And I need to create a button dynamically. I can't use new Button(this). Because I'm not extending activity. How do I do this?

```
public class Tab2Fragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    LinearLayout theLayout =  (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2, container, false);

    Context mFragmentContext=getActivity().getApplicationContext(); 
    Button btn=new Button(mFragmentContext);
    btn.setText("Hello Button");
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsd = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(150,30);
    paramsd.height = 600;
    paramsd.width = 60;
    btn.setLayoutParams(paramsd);
    addContentView(btn,paramsd);
```

Comment: pass the Activity or application context instead of "this".

Comment: I tried making a new activity and putting it in space of "this" but the app crashed. Where should i be passing the activity from? Sorry I'm kinda new to this. How do I know what the application context is?

Comment: where is your 'setContentView' ???

Comment: its a fragment so I used this method LinearLayout theLayout =  (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2, container, false); I added it into my code

Answer (score 3):

//try using this below code

**sol1:**

```
Button myButt=new Button(YourFragmentClass.this);
```

**sol2:**

```
Button myButt=new Button(getApplicationContext());
```

//you can also get context like this

```
 private Context mFragmentContext=getActivity().getApplicationContext();
```

Comment: Ok I'm trying the private context method you posted, but how do i add the button to my view so it actually shows up in the app?

Comment: without posting your code do you want to  do all your homework.

Comment: alright i edited it and added my code, the method addContentView worked on a class where Activity was extended but not on my fragment class

Answer (score 0):

```
/* getActivity() will give you the Activity this fragment belongs
to, you can use this as 'Context' */

Button button = new Button(getActivity())

/* getView() will give you the root layout for this fragment 
(Relative, Linear or whatever you used in xml) and you must cast it
to a ViewGroup to access the getView() method*/

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsd = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(150,30);
paramsd.height = 600;
paramsd.width = 60;

ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) getView();
viewGroup.addView(button, paramsd);
```

See here for more info on getView(): [Android add button to Fragment without id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18913604/android-add-button-to-fragment-without-id)

Happy Coding...