# Android add button to Fragment without id

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to display a button in the left down corner of a fragment but I don't know the Id of the fragment's main layout as I am in an abstract class that has no layout.

```
@EFragment(R.layout.exercise_test)
public class Exercise1 extends Exercice

public abstract class Exercice extends Fragment{

   public void showValidateButton()
   {
       Button validateButton = new Button(this.getActivity().getBaseContext());
       validateButton.setText("OK");
       // Here I want to add the button to Exercise1 
   }
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this ?

Thank you

Thierry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Fragment's [`getView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getView%28%29) method to get the root view containing all the Layout of the Fragment. As long at this is a `ViewGroup` you can add your Button using the addView() method.

However to place if correctly, you'd have some knowledge about the Layout used, e.g. RelativeLayout, LinearLayout etc.

A more hardcore solution would be to create your own RelativeLayout, add the result of Fragment's getView() and your own Button and set your RelativeLayout as the new Root View of the Fragment.

Comment: Thank you ! The first option suited perfectly, I forgot to cast the getView() return to a ViewGroup so I had no access to the addView() method.